# AWS S3 copy using key and secret

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I have been given by a client the the s3 key, secret, region and bucket name.

1. I am trying to copy clients S3 bucket contents to an s3 bucket in my account.
2. I want to do it one off
3. I want to copy it directly from client S3 bucket to my account S3 bucket. I do not want to download the files to my ec2 instance and then copy to S3.

Comment: "copy this"? what is "this"? "copy it"? what is "it"?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Are you wanting to copy a file from their S3 bucket to your S3 bucket? Would it be okay to simply download it, then re-upload it, or do you particularly want to copy directly between the buckets? Is this one-off, or do you want to automate it for future use? Please edit your question to add details (NOT in comments please).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the best practice (best practice would be cross-account access and instance role), but for one off thing this should do. If files are large - your best bet would be to do it within EC2 instance.

Get the machine with sufficient disk space to hold the content of the S3 bucket.

[Install aws cli](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/install-cliv2.html) if not installed already

Configure aws cli with your and client's credentials under different profiles.

```
$aws configure --profile my-account
AWS Access Key ID [None]: ABCD...98
AWS Secret Access Key [None]: ZXY...98
Default region name [None]: 
Default output format [None]: 

$aws configure --profile customer-account
AWS Access Key ID [None]: A123...98
AWS Secret Access Key [None]: Z98A...98
Default region name [None]: 
Default output format [None]:
```

copy content of the customer's bucket locally:

```
$aws s3 cp s3://customer-bucket ./localdirectory --recursive --profile customer-account
```

upload local files to your s3 bucket:

```
$aws s3 cp ./localdirectory s3://my-bucket  --recursive --profile my-account
```